# Upgrade Ruby version while deploying to EB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a production rails application on Ruby `2.2.5` but I updated my app to ruby `2.5.3` and rails from `4.2` to `5.2`. When I try to deploy this to ElasticBeanstalk I get the following errors everytime:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. 
We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Your Ruby version is 2.2.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

To fix this I ssh'd into the instance and installed `rvm` before updating the ruby version using

`rvm --default use 2.5.3`

After this I updated my `bundler` as suggested in the error message but it seems like the ruby version gets reset to `2.2.5` everytime I close my connection and `ssh` in again because doing

`ruby -v` gives `2.2.5`

How can I update the ruby version on my instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk sets the Ruby version in the Platform (you can think of this as the base AMI). To upgrade this you'll need to [update your platform version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.platform.upgrade.html).

Depending on the web server you use, it sounds like you'll need one of:

- 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.7 running Ruby 2.5 (Puma)
- 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.7 running Ruby 2.5 (Passenger Standalone)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't know that's how it was supposed to be done, it does look like I will create a new Environment with the updated configuration though because I can't see an option to directly update the ruby version